# When first require() invoked, Does node js do caching? With Next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js

```js
// FILE A.js
let users;
class A () {
  static init() {
    users = 'abc';
  }

  static addSomething () {
    return users.slice(1);
  }
}
module.exports = A;
```

```
// FILE A_1.js
const A = require('./A');
A.init();
```

```
// FILE A_2.js
const A = require('./A');
A.addSomething();
```

When I invoke A_2.js file, It throws error **Can't call slice on undefined.**

I heard something like when first require fired, it's cached.

I re-write `module.exports = A` to `module.exports.default = A;`
And `const A = require().default;`
It doesn't work like before.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: In next.js src/page/api and custom folder src/dao/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the pseudocode on question.

It was split with next.js API dir, and custom model dir.

I found the information.
https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/eiykfc/share_database_connection_in_nextjs_api_routes/

It looks like next.js serverless philosophy it's self.

***This won't work when Next.js splits each API route into its own bundle with Webpack, will it? For me it did not cache modules between API routes, at least in development mode.***

Comment: And I found this article 
https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nextjs-building-modern-applications